Transforming a second-order ODE into a familiar form
Suppose $y(x)$ satisfies the ODE
$$\left(\frac{C}{x}+2\right)y''-\frac{C}{x^2}y'+\left(\frac{C}{x^3}+D\right)y = 0,$$
where $C, D$ are nonzero constants.
Note: multiplying both sides of the equation by $\frac{x^3}{C}$ generates a form that looks close to an extended Bessel or Kummer function ODE, however not exactly of any type. Also, the first two terms on the left-hand-side can be combined into a single term $\left[\left(\frac{C}{x}+2\right)y'\right]'$, but that seems not suggesting any useful transformation either
